# Get mysql value into php variable

Tags: php, mysql, usersession

I have a site set up with a mysql DB that stores user data. The database structure looks like this:

```
table = users

columns = Id : username : email : password : active
```

Under the column `active` the value is 1 for active and 0 for deactive

When a user pays for my site, the `active` value changes from 0 to 1.

I want to show now if a user has paid or not at the user profile.

How can I query the database to get the value of the `active` column based on the `username` and save it as a variable to use later in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
<?php
            $sql = new mysqli ("host","user","pass" ,"db"); //EDIT with your parameters for DB
            $sql -> set_charset ( 'utf8' );
            if ($sql->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $sql->connect_error);
            exit();}


$user = $_SESSION['username']; // for example, you need to know what you are looking for

$q = "SELECT active FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";
if ($result = $sql->query($q)) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$active = $row['active']; 
}}
```

You know have $active with value 1 or 0 and can echo it whereever you want

**EDIT**

You will need to change your connect.php, in case you haven't yet. Can you please post it without your credentials, it's best to edit your question with the new code

```
session_start();
require('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_POST['username']); //for security
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_POST['password']); //for security
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";


if ($result = $sql->query($query)) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$active = $row['active']; }
        $count = $result->num_rows; //and this, too
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think while loop is necessary

Comment: thank you for the fast reply you saved my life the coder i paid vanished on me before he finished the script now i need to try finish it with limited knolage

Comment: @reenleedr - I know, you are right, I just allways write it, don't know why

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it has helped you. You know how to deal with $_SESSION?

Comment: hi yes i have spent a few hours reading over the script and looking over parts i need to fix just started working on the db connections now

Comment: Cool, if you have questions let me know

Comment: hi michael i was wondering if you could help just once more i was wondering if you could work the code above into the code i have to connect to my db  code bellow if the users active value =1 i want to include account .php

Comment: <?php  //Start the Session
session_start();
 require('connect.php');
//3. If the form is submitted or not.
//3.1 If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the databa

Comment: I've just edited the answer with the new code, can you please paste your connect.php without your credentials, then I can have a look at it

Comment: Edited again to put the other stuff in

Comment: <?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'x', 'D');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('xd');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>

Comment: Change the connect.php to the first part of my answer, this: <?php
            $sql = new mysqli ("host","user","pass" ,"db"); //EDIT with your parameters for DB
            $sql -> set_charset ( 'utf8' );
            if ($sql->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $sql->connect_error);
            exit();} and edit the credentials

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look on mysqli_ at php.net. The mysql_ functions you are using are deprecated since php 5.5 and shouldn't be used anymore. This means you should rewrite the entire code to mysqli_

Comment: ho michale i was wonder if you had skype to help me please i have added your code into the site and changed the other files like connect and register but i am having a problem with my index file